# Self-join a table to merge multiple rows in to one row

Tags: sql

I am very new to SQL and never did anything complex like this. Any help would be appreciated.

I have following data in the table:

```
ID - TAG
1  - U
1  - N
1  - U
1  - N
1  - U
```

My output needs to be

```
ID - U  - N
1  - 3  - 2
```

Basically my output needs to count N's and U's for the ID and produce a single row for that ID.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  ID,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN TAG = 'U' THEN 1 END) AS [U],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN TAG = 'N' THEN 1 END) AS [N]
FROM
  someTable
GROUP BY
  ID
```

UPDATE:

Another poster (see below) points out that I used square brackets where some RDBMSs require double quotes.

Comment: +1 for the general solution that should work anywhere. You might want to note that you're using SQL Server's quoting convention rather than standard quoting though.

Comment: I was talking about the `[U]` and `[N]`, standard SQL would want `"U"` and `"N"` for quoted identifiers. I'm pretty sure everyone is happy with single quotes for string literals (or at least I hope so). But yeah, tunnel vision :)

Comment: Hi John, Thanks a lot. That worked. I was actually trying to accomplish this is an ETL job but SQL was much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL this is simplier than you think :)

```
select id,
    sum(if(tag = 'U', 1, 0)) as U,
    sum(if(tag = 'N', 1, 0)) as N
from table1
group by id
```

Basically, for each id you get you create a new column (U and N) which will have a 1 or a 0 based on whether tag has value 'U' or 'N'. This results in something like this:

```
+----+---+---+
| ID | U | N |
+----+---+---+
|  1 | 1 | 0 |
|  1 | 0 | 1 |
|  1 | 1 | 0 |
|  1 | 0 | 1 |
|  1 | 1 | 0 |
+----+---+---+
```

Now, all we have to do is group by ID and sum all values from U and N, and we get:

```
+----+---+---+
| ID | U | N |
+----+---+---+
|  1 | 3 | 2 |
+----+---+---+
```

Hope this helps.